# Two settings for same project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have a project which has a shared codebase between web and TV. It is built on ReactJS. That's not the point though.

We have components with same names but for different build targets.

Is it somehow possible to have list of files with for each individual platform?

Given that you have structure like:

```
src/
    web/
        Component.js
    tv/
        Component.js
```

I'd like to have a `settings-web.json` which will ignore `tv` folder so when I press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> I'll see just:

```
src/
    web/
        Component.js
```

And also a `setting-tv.json` which will do the opposite. It would definitely improve the development experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do so, in the root of each you can place a `jsconfig.json`. This will tell `vscode` that this is a different project then the workspace as a whole, so it would looks something like this:

```
src/
    web/
        Component.js
        jsconfig.json
    tv/
        Component.js
        jsconfig.json
```

Next you will want to modify each one to include the files you would like to be apart of that project. For example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "files": [
        "./Component.js"
    ]
}
```

You can also use `include` and `exclude` (`exclude` is omitted if `files` is set).

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: Their is one issue though, you can't build them in one easy keyboard shortcut at the moment, but they are working on a solution to that. To build you will have to make two seperate tasks and run them separately, or use gulp/grunt until they have a solution with `tasks.json`